# Specifying string patterns in a plain text

Tags: pattern-matching

1. I need to extract three data, like that: (1.05, 1.37,A) from an imported list of  plain texts:

"... Syntax of parallax is : 'value quality [error] bibcode' 
value : parallax value  quality : flag of quality (A=best quality -> E=worst quality, ~ =unknown quality)  [error] : mean error  bibcode : bibcode of the parallax reference     Parallaxes mas :        1.05 [1.37] A 2007A&A...474..653V...,

........ Parallaxes mas :        xxxxxx [xxxxx] xxx ................., etc...."

I did the following code:

```
datatoda = Import[".............", "Plaintext"];

In[28]:= StringCases[datatoda, "Parallaxes mas :" ~~ __ ~~ (x : NumberString) ~~ "[" ~~ (y : NumberString) ~~ "]" ~~ (z : WordCharacter ...) ~~ DatePattern["Year"]~~__ :> ToExpression@{x, y, z}]

Out[28]= {{}}
```

But I can not see where I am failing.

I need a list like that:{  {1.05,1.37,A},{....,...,.....}, etc.......           }

2. Sometimes there is no numbers in pattern of the plain text data ( Parallaxes mas : ~ [~] ~ ~  ) , in that case the sublist has to be {{..,...,..},......,***{N/A}***,...etc}. How can I implement it?

EDIT1.: This is an e.g of link where the plaint text comes from: 
http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%402515791&Name=HD%20164816&submit=submit
Thanks!

Comment: I think you have not allowed for some spaces in your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I Got a positive result using :

```
StringCases[datatoda, {"Help" ~~ RegularExpression["\\s+"] ~~ a : __ ~~ RegularExpression["\\s+"] ~~ "other" ~~ RegularExpression["\\s"] ~~ ___ ~~ "Parallaxes mas :" ~~ RegularExpression["\\s+"] ~~ x : NumberString ~~ RegularExpression["\\s"] ~~ "[" ~~ y : NumberString ~~ "]" ~~ RegularExpression["\\s"] ~~ z : WordCharacter ~~ RegularExpression["\\s"] ~~ "2007A&A" :> StringTrim@{a, x, y, z}}];
```

(I  introduced, also, a new data also in the sublist)

```
{{{"HD 164019", "1.05", "1.37", "A"}}, {{"* 63 Oph", "-0.77", "0.40", "A"}}, {{"HD 168941", "-3.76", "1.38", "A"}}, {}, {}, {{"* 9 Sgr", "0.49", "0.40", "A"}}, {}, {{"HD 165052", "0.15", "0.63", "A"}}, {{"* zet Oph", "8.91", "0.20", "A"}}, {}}
```

Has anibody a simpler code suggestion?